# Salesforce Sandbox Code Deployment

Tags: deployment, sandbox

This is a very generic and high level question of which I wanted to have a clarity.

I have 10 Sandboxes and I decided to change a validation rule in one of the sandbox. How do I copy this change to the rest of the other sandboxes?

Please help me to get a clarity on this scenario.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by deploying your rule to all sandboxes.

Use Change sets to deploy(there are many tools out there other than change set), but its simple to start with.

In deployment settings, connect your sandboxes and build Outbound change set in your source and add it to the change set and upload.

Deployment settings: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dev_lifecycle.meta/dev_lifecycle/migrate_deployment_connection.htm

You have to do it this multiple times to get it to all sandboxes.

Below trailhead will give you a better understanding: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/app_deployment/units/app_deployment_changesets

Comment: Does this work same for deleting a validation rule also? Is there any other way other than doing it multiple time to get it to all sandboxes or is that the only way?

Comment: Unfortunately, salesforce isn't flexible with Change sets while deleting stuff. But there are many tools out there that can do the job. Bluefox, autorabbit etc that are easy from UI. But if you want use change set, i think you can move the whole object from source to destination after deleting manually in source.

Comment: May I add my company's product, Snapshot, to the mix here when it comes to deployments (constructive or destructive)? There is a two week trial if you want to compare features or ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using the [Ant Migration Tool.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_install.htm) It does have a little big of setup and a learning curve. But once you get accustomed to using it, it's a lot quicker then having to deal with change-sets across multiple environments.